# How can I access the Workspace object from a training script in AzureML?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to access the Workspace object in my `train.py` script, when running in an Estimator.

I currently can access the Run object, using the following code:

```py
run = Run.get_context()
```

But I cannot seem to get my hands on the Workspace object in my training script.  I would use this mostly to get access to the Datastores and Datasets (as I would hope to keep all data set references inside the training script, instead of passing them as input datasets)

Any idea if/how this is possible ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, try this:

```
from azureml.core.run import Run
run = Run.get_context()
ws = run.experiment.workspace
```

Comment: this works for azureml sdkv1 but not in azureml sdkv2 (azure.ai.ml). How might one get the workspace object, aka MLClient, inside a sdkv2 pipeline step? I.e. What's the sdkv2 equivalent of Run.get_context().experiment.workspace ?